# Is there a better way to insert array values dynamically to an excel sheet?

Tags: javascript, arrays, excel

Currently the array values are inserted in the worksheet no problem, but only works when the start value of the range is A1, other start values return an error and will not work. Is there a way to make A2 as the start of the range?

```
let sheetValuesRange = sheet.getRange("A1:CK44");

sheetValuesRange.load(["values"]);

await context.sync();

let allValues = sheetValuesRange.values;

let dataArray = [];
allValues.forEach(function(row, index) {
  let ftrId = 9;
  if (row[24] > 0) {
    dataArray.push([row[64], ftrId, row[24]]);
  }
});

// Print array data to worksheet

let dataRange = sheet1.getRange(`A1:C${dataArray.length}`);

dataRange.values = dataArray;
```

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: It's a an office add-in called Script Lab that uses an Office JavaScript API in excel